# Is it possible to instantiate Jaxb once, and use it in all Apache Camel routes?

Tags: java, jaxb, apache-camel

I've a route that ends with a marshal into xml, with the use of Jaxb. The entire route takes only mere milliseconds, until the time that the Jaxb context has to be instantiated:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(VVTMPUSH.class);
```

This small method takes around two seconds. And it is called every time the route is used, which should be around 100 times per second.
Is it possible to instantiate the `Jaxbcontext` only once, and use that same object in every route?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm creating it myself. It's part of a async process. But thanks, did not know about that. I'll give it a try!

Comment: Deleted my comment and added it as an answer with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've split the original `process` in two, removed the initialisation of Jaxb from the method, added it to camel route and created a new `process_2` that continued what previously was in `process_1`

```
JaxbDataFormat jaxb = new JaxbDataFormat("add.your.namespace.to.the.ObjectFactory");
jaxb.setPrettyPrint(true);

from("seda:out?concurrentConsumers=20")
    .process(new process_1())
    .marshal(jaxb)
    .process(new process_2());
```